# Jenkins multi-branch pipelines' other repo's jobs triggered with bitbucket webhook push

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

Using Jenkins 2.263.2, I configured Bitbucket webhook and Jenkinsfile (declarative jenkins pipeline).

When I push a commit to repo A, other multi-branch pipelines' jobs (i.e. pipelines for repo B-E) are triggered.

It seems that pushing to only repo A would trigger other pipelines.

I tried all of these:

```
triggers { 
   bitbucketPush()
}
```

Tried overriding Repository URL (https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-plugin#override-repository-url)

```
triggers { 
   bitbucketPush overrideUrl: 'https://bitbucket.org/xxx/repo-name'  
}
```

Tried adding property "Suppress Automatic SCM Trigger" to job configuration (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53769527)

[image]

What I'm observing is when unrelated repo's jobs are triggered, their repo's webhook request are not there, neither is Jenkins scan log for that repo.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas how to stop multiple unrelated Jenkins jobs to be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i accomplished, hope it works for you too.

## for pipelineJob

```
pipelineJob('pipeline-job-1') {

    configure { project ->
    
        project / 'properties' / 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty' / triggers / 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitBucketTrigger' {
            spec()
            overrideUrl('git@foo.bar:baz/repo.git')
        }
    }

    /// some codes

}
```

## for multibranchPipelineJob

```
multibranchPipelineJob('my-multibranch-job1') {

 configure { project ->
        
        project / triggers / 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitBucketMultibranchTrigger' {
            spec()
            overrideUrl('git@foo.bar:baz/repo.git')
        }
    }

    /// some codes

}
```

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block